# Hebrew 12:6 scourging or correction?

Tags: contradiction, hebrews

In Hebrew 12:6 we can read
“For whom the Lord loveth he chasteneth, and scourgeth every son whom he receiveth.”
Chastening : G3811 Paideuo can also mean instruct or train (even scourge) a child
Scourge: G3146 Mastigoo which is far more explicit as it is used only for harsh physical punishment (eg:used for the scourging of Jesus by the romains)
This verse is directly referring to Prov 3:12. In Hebrew the word is correct H3198 yakach and does not mean scourge.

The scourging of God’s children seams to be out of step with the overall NT teaching.

Q1 the NT has to be considered as a commentary of the OT. In this case the meaning is far harder in the NT than in the OT. Can we consider in this case that the OT is the commentary of the NT?

Q2 How can we reconcile the scourging of God’s children with 1Peter 2 24 ( by whose stripes ye were healed) and Isai 53:5?
(the chastisement of our peace was upon him; and with his stripes we are healed)

Answer (score 1):

And you have completely forgotten the exhortation which reasons with you as with sons, "My son, do not regard lightly the discipline of the Lord, nor faint when reproved by Him; for whom the Lord loves He disciplines, and He scourges every son whom He receives."

Hebrews 12:5-6 above looks to be directly from the Septuagint Proverbs 3:11-12: My son, despise not the chastening of the Lord; nor faint when thou art rebuked of him:
for whom the Lord loves, he rebukes, and scourges every son whom he receives.

Instead of directly from the Hebrew Proverbs we have: My son, do not despise the chastening of Jehovah, nor be weary of His discipline; for whom Jehovah loves He disciplines, even as a father, the son in whom he delights.

The Septuagint seems to translate and comment on the OT. I'm not sure what every son **He receives** means. Every son He has? Every son He loves? Hebrews 12:7-8, as a commentary on the OT, sounds like every son He has. It is for discipline that you endure; God deals with you as with sons. For what son is there whom the father does not discipline? But if you are without discipline, of which all sons have become partakers, then you are illegitimate and not sons.

Proverbs elsewhere talks about physical discipline (not abuse! cf Eph 6:4) of one's children. I feel that the scourging of God’s children is not God's goal, but's in step with the overall NT teaching (and OT teaching and typology) of salvation. Which is sonship.

Predestinating us unto sonship through Jesus Christ to Himself, according to the good pleasure of His will. Ephesians 1:5. That He might redeem those under law that we might receive the sonship. Galatians 4:5. That which is born of the flesh is flesh, and that which is **born** of the Spirit is spirit. Do not marvel that I said to you, You must be born anew. John 3:6-7. For you have not received a spirit of slavery bringing you into fear again, but you have received a spirit of sonship in which we cry, Abba, Father! Romans 8:15.

As wonderful as adoption is, God's salvation begins with birth and is not adoption. Receiving the Spirit is not as a marble in a can, that can be undone. But rather permanent mingling like conception. He who is joined to the Lord is one spirit. 1 Corinthians 6:17. It is not the false sad Pelagianistic teaching that one can lose one's second birth, so as to need to be re-reborn, or to be eternally condemned.

Isaiah 53:5. But He was wounded because of our transgressions; he was crushed because of our iniquities; the chastening for our peace was upon Him, and by His stripes we have been healed. People can never pay for their sins so as to be righteous. We can't justify ourselves. Neither can we make ourselves sons or live the life of God without God. 53:5 covers both His death, scourging, for our guilt and His death for our freedom from sin the life of sin. Only His death, His scourging, can do that. Colossians 2:11-14.

All this without getting to what I think's the meat of your questions: **What's the nature of scourging that Christians can receive?** I'll leave that for another. Except to say that the Father's discipline of His children is to encourage us to choose to walk by the Spirit in our spirit, rather than to live by ourselves. (Mt 16:24; Heb 12:9-11. Verses like Mt 10:33; Heb 12:17, 29 speak of discipline too, at another juncture.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not question the correction and the chastening that are for instruction (eg: through the Word of God or from a brother). My question is about the scourging which is for punishment. How can God’s sons be scourged if Jesus took this punishment on him at the cross?

Comment: All punishment of saints is discipline for correction. Even in the next age. And like the "quarantining" of the brother in 1 Corinthians 5. He wasn't paying his debt for his sin, which Christ did for him. Instead he was separated so as to realize the gravity of what he did and not "infect" the other saints and repent. God's discipline of us often doesn't involve sin, but is for the purpose of helping us love Christ (Philip 1:21) instead of loving ourselves (Gal 2:20). Which isn't a small thing, but is everything. Christ's death for our guilt was on the negative side. Sonship's affirmative.